# DateDiff in SQL Server asking for help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table which has a datetime type column called CreateTime. I need to select all the records from this table whose CreateTime is more than 3 days and half an hour from current time (UTC time). I am using T-SQL store procedure.

BTW: The CreateTime column is some time in the past time.

I have taken quite some time to learn and search for help from MSDN for DateDiff, but cannot figure out. Could anyone show me a sample please?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select and add a WHERE clause with a DATEDIFF using minutes:

```
SELECT (fields)
FROM (table)
WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CREATETIME, getutcdate()) <= (3*24*60 + 30)
```

And of course, if you only wants those rows which are **MORE** than 3 days and 30 minutes away, just use the opposite:

```
WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CREATETIME, getutcdate()) > (3*24*60 + 30)
```

A sample:

```
SELECT      
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2009-08-01 08:00:00', getutcdate()),
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2009-07-31 20:00:00', getutcdate()),
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2009-07-23 20:00:00', getutcdate())
```

gives as result:

```
96    816    12337
```

So the first two dates are still within your 4350 minute bracket (less than 3 days and 30 minutes ago), while the third date is further away.

Marc

Comment: If CREATETIME is greater than getdateutc() the value will be negative. It should be -(3*24*60 + 30)

Comment: So that would be a row that will be created some time in the future, right? :-) Sounds like a time machine thingie to me......

Comment: Hello everyone, sorry I have not made myself fully understood. The Createtime is something in the past. I think I should use the following T-SQL, correct?

WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 4350, [CreationTime]) > GETUTCDATE()

Comment: The example is correct for the problem as stated.  DATEDIFF yields a positive number when the second date is greater than the first.

Answer (score 3):

You need [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
WHERE DATEADD(minute, 4350, CreateTime) <= getutcdate()
```

Or, as you mentioned, you can use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, CreateTime, getutcdate()) <= 4350
```

(4350 is '3 days and 30 minutes' in minutes)

Comment: The question actually specifies 3 days and half an hour, not 1 day.

Comment: Thanks Richard, in your SQL statement, the first parameter '.' means?

Comment: Thanks Richard, I find two issues in your code. :-)

1. getdateutc is not recognized by SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, I need to use GETUTCDATE;
2. I think I should use WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 4350, [CreationTime]) > GETUTCDATE(), other than WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 4350, GETUTCDATE())> [CreationTime], because time in the past is always smaller?

Answer (score 2):

One minor quibble with the given answers, though they are correct. Don't apply the function to the column: apply the function to the comparison value.

If CREATETIME is indexed then it's a scan rather than seek with the function on the column. 
You don't need millions of rows for this to be a problem.

Adapting the answer of marc_s:

```
SELECT (fields)
FROM (table)
WHERE 
  CREATETIME <= DATEADD(MINUTE, - (3*24*60 + 30), getutcdate())
```